# jquery droppable, dropping on invisible item when container set to overflow:auto

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a div that have a fixed size and overflow:auto.

If I drop somewhere near the droppableDiv, the item is dropped into the invisible area of the droppableDiv,(that is where the droppable should have been if there wasn't any scrollbar) 
I tried to fix that problem using a z-index property so that the div is far behind any other div. it doesn't work.

How to prevent dropping on invisible droppables due to overflow ?
Thank you

This is an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/Etx4t/3/
Try to drop below the droppable container, and you'll see that the droppable is detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i cannot reproduce your problem. see:

http://jsfiddle.net/Etx4t/1/

this means that your problem is not what you think it is.

based on your updated fiddle here is a hack to solve your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/Etx4t/4/

i cant think of a better way to do this

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer, actually this is my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Etx4t/3/ try dropping below the scrollable div